# My number of figure display in paragraph

Tags: floats, paragraphs

I don't know which part of code make it happened

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%LIST OF FIGURES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
\if@draftmode\else
    \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
    \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}
    \renewcommand{\@althead}{\hspace{0.3\textwidth}LIST OF FIGURES~(Cont.)\hfil}
    \pagestyle{headings}
    \thispagestyle{tocheadings}
    \linespacing{1.3}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalfont \MakeTextUppercase\listfigurename}
    \@starttoc{lof} % must go after addcontentsline
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
\fi
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

-

```
\newcommand{\figuretable}[3]{\begin{tabu}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{#1}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Project}: \@title \newline\newline \textbf{System}: {#2} \newline & \textbf{Major Advisor}:\newline \@majoradvisor \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr \linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{\textbf{Description}: {#3} \newline} \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
}
```

-

```
%Figure 2.3: “Film” entity in wikidata
\ref{fig:203}.
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/chap2/203.png}
\caption{“Film” entity in wikidata}
\label{fig:203}
\end{figure}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Erh, you made a reference, inserted a float, the float did not fit there on the page and is thus inserted on the next page. See the first line of the last sniplet

Comment: @daleif sorry for my slow learning skill, but seriously I don't understand what you trying to explain...

Comment: @daleif Oh wait... I'm already understand, thank you very much.